# Insert text before and after the selected text in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to put some specified text (where possible/any editable field) before and after any selected text in an HTML document.
`document.getSelection()` or `document.selection.createRange().text` returns only the text itself not the position. 
Is there anyway to replace the selected text? Anyway to insert specific text before and after selcted text anywhere in the document?

Comment: Could you get the string, add what you want to the beginning & end, then reinsert in the original position?

Comment: How to 'reinsert' to 'original position'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a cross-browser function to do this, which works in all major browsers and caters for the vastly different way IE does this compared  to other browsers.

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/timdown/UWExN/64/

```
function insertHtmlAtSelectionEnd(html, isBefore) {
    var sel, range, node;
    if (window.getSelection) {
        sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
            range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
            range.collapse(isBefore);

            // Range.createContextualFragment() would be useful here but was
            // until recently non-standard and not supported in all browsers
            // (IE9, for one)
            var el = document.createElement("div");
            el.innerHTML = html;
            var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(), node, lastNode;
            while ( (node = el.firstChild) ) {
                lastNode = frag.appendChild(node);
            }
            range.insertNode(frag);
        }
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
        range = document.selection.createRange();
        range.collapse(isBefore);
        range.pasteHTML(html);
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry, my mistake of parameters

Comment: @LifeH2O: What's the problem?

Comment: in internet explorer 8 i am getting unspecified error at 'range.pasteHTML(html);'  where isAfter was true, and html was 'a text'

Comment: see this http://jsfiddle.net/srGqE/ when i click in blank area above button and then click it, 'a text' is added before text area

Comment: @LifeH2O: I did get the `isAfter` parameter the wrong way round, and changed it to `isBefore` instead.

Comment: @LifeH20: No, it won't work in a textarea. You need a separate mechanism for that.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var r = document.selection.createRange();

r.text = "before" + r.text;
r.text += "after";
```

Comment: @Tim: It is - for others there is window.getSelection ().getRangeAt ( 0 ).insert/appendNode ( document.createTextNode ( "before/after" ) );

Comment: This also will remove any HTML from the current selection and replace it with text only.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code to get the insertion and replacement with a text node and `range.insertNode()`.

**Text inserter**

```
function textInserter(isBefore) {
  const selection = window.getSelection();
  const range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
  if (isBefore) {
    range.collapse(true);
  } else {
    range.collapse(false);
  }
  const textNode = document.createTextNode('"Text"');
  range.insertNode(textNode);
}
```

**Text Replacer**

```
function textReplacer() {
  const selection = window.getSelection();
  const range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
  range.extractContents(); 
  const textNode = document.createTextNode('"Replacing Text"');
  range.insertNode(textNode);
}
```

You can check the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gooner12/u25cbdyw/2/